# print all array values inside one input

Tags: php

I just want to print out all the values in array to a input. currently when I am doing this using this code

```
echo "<input type='text' value='<?php echo $files() ?>' />";
```

What it returns is

```
<?php echo Array() ?>
```

Instead I want to see all the values inside an array.

Can I explain more or provide a link ?

Comment: to print out all the values, you either have to use a loop or implode them into one string. otherwise, $file will be implicitely converted to the string `"Array"`. and normal parentheses `()` are not how you access array elements.

Comment: what is `$files()` ?

Answer (score 0):

> First; You just can't Print an Array in PHP. You may first need to convert the Array to String before Printing. Second; ***you don't `echo` within an echo Statement:*** `echo "<input type='text' value='<?php echo $files() ?>' />";`
> That was why you had: `<?php echo Array() ?>` since $files is an Array. As you can see it is just echoing a PHP line of code: Verbatim. That is the effect of echoing within an echo Statement.
> Anyways; here are a few  Options:

```
  <?php

    // CONVERT TO STRING USING IMPLODE; THEN ECHO:
    echo "<input type='text' value='";
    echo implode(", ", $files()) . "'/>";  


    // VAR_DUMP THE VARIABLE TO  SEE IT'S CONTENTS: NOT FOR USE
    echo "<input type='text' value='";
    var_dump( $files() ); 
    echo "' />"; 



    // BUILD A STRING-OUTPUT FROM LOOPING THROUGH THE $files();
    $output      = "";
    foreach($files() as $index=>$value){
        $output .= (is_string($value) || is_numeric($value)) ? $value . ", " : "";            
    }
    echo "<input type='text' value='";
    echo $output . "'/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow bellow code :

```
<?php 
$value = '';
foreach($files() as $val){
    $value .= $val.",";
}
$all_values = rtrim($value, ',');

echo "<input type='text' value='".$all_values."' />";
?>
```